# Why is Xamarin Forms iOS ignoring certain HTML tags in Labels with TextType set to Html?

Tags: html, ios, xamarin.forms, label

The Xamarin Forms **Label** class **TextType** Property value of **Html** works fine in my Android app, but in **iOS** seems to ignore the following tag types in my app:

- `<b>`
- `<font color ="#f44336">`
- `<small>`

Here is an example of the string I passing in to Label.Text:

```
"<b><font color ="#f44336">Bold red text: </font></b><font color ="#0070C0">blue text</font><br/><b><font color ="#f44336">More bold red: </font></b>black text<br/>"
```

Any reason why this might be happening?

Comment: Just in case its some subtlety of something else in your html, please **add to question** a **small** snippet of HTML that you've verified has this symptom. Do this by "hardcoding" the HTML as a string, to eliminate possible issues involving character decoding (if you are receiving the HTML from elsewhere).

Comment: Just added. Please see above.

Comment: Any further thoughts on this?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. <p> and <h2> tags are not working. Text is shown as plain text only. On Android it's working.